# html. Квадратные скобки в коде ( [text] )

Tags: html

Разбираюсь с движком dle, в файле шаблона `.tpl` обнаружил незнакомую мне вещь, квадратные скобки с каким-то текстом в html.

```
<div class="course1">
                    <div class="cfi_item course_name" itemprop="name"><b>Углубленный курс</b></div>
                    <div class="cfi_item">
                        <div class="ci_text"><i class="fa fa-calendar-check-o"></i> <span>Срок:</span></div> <div class="ci_text">[xfvalue_sro]</div>
                    </div>
                    [xfgiven_rezhim]
                    <div class="cfi_item">
                        <div class="ci_text">
                            <i class="fa fa-users"></i> <span>График:</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ci_text">[xfvalue_rezhim]</div>
                    </div>
                    [/xfgiven_rezhim]
                    [xfgiven_stoimost]
                    <div class="cfi_item" itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">[xfgiven_p1]<meta itemprop="price" content="[xfvalue_p1]">[/xfgiven_p1]
                        <div class="ci_text">
                            <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="RUB">
                            <i class="fa fa-calculator"></i> <span>Цена:</span></div> <div class="ci_text">[xfvalue_stoimost]
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    [/xfgiven_stoimost]
                    <div class="btn_buy">[group=5]<a href="/index.php?do=register">[/group][not-group=5]<a href="/pupil/pay/courses">[/not-group]Купить</a></div>
                </div>
```

Что означают эти квадратные скобки, например `[xfgiven_rezhim]` в 6 строке, этот кусок кода взят из шаблона `.tpl`.

P.S. Ничего толкового по этому поводу не нашёл.

P.S.S.  Вместо квадратных скобок на страницы появляются значения, прям как переменные php.

P.S.S.S. В коде нашел еще и такой кусок кода `{include file="calendar_list.tpl"}`

Comment: Похоже на bb код, или какой-то js фреймворк типа angular

Comment: Да, но только здесь нет тегов типа `<script></script>`

Comment: Это не обязательно

Comment: Это может быть парсер.

Comment: Это же не html, а tpl. То есть, предполагается, что он будет пререндериться неким инструментом. Движков шаблонизации тысячи - это может быть что угодно.